# How to retrieve data from Firebase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one node named as ***group_chat*** and another one named as ***users***. The node ***group_chat*** contains the children which contains message, time and sender_id. Whereas the node ***users*** contains the details of users. When I retrieve chats from ***group_chat*** node, I also want to display the information of each sender. On using this code

```
rootChat.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.val().sender_id == logged_in_user_id) {
        // Message by You
        // Print snapshot.val().message
    }
    else{
        const refUser = "/users/"+snapshot.val().sender_id;
        const rootUser = database.ref(refUser);
        rootUser.once("value", function(snap) {
            // Print snap.val().name
            // Display snap.val().picture

            // Print snapshot.val().message
        });
    }
    
});
```

The problem is, when the code goes in else condition where it's the message of the other user, it retrieves the information of the user by going through the specific node. But while doing it, it automatically goes to next child while going through the user detail of first child which automatically spoils the arrangement of messages showing latest message in the middle, middle one in end and so on.
If I have 4 children named as -child1, -child2, -child3 and -child4 in node ***group_chat***, while checking the -child1, it will also check -child2 and sometimes it will print -child 2 before -child1.
How can I resolve it? Is there any way where I can wait for the else condition to finish and then go to next child? Or is there any way where I can get user detail in just one line of code somehow like this

```
// rootUser.child.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about pre-loading the users, before you start building the HTML?

The outline of that would be something like:

1. Use `on("value"` instead of `on("child_added`, so that you get all messages in one go.
2. Loop over the messages to determine the unique user IDs.
3. Load all users with `once("value")` calls. Note that `once()` returns a promise, so you can wait to all users to be loaded with `Promise.all()`.
4. Now loop over all messages again to build the HTML.
5. At this point if you need user data, you can look it up without needing an asynchronous call.

Comment: Yes that works for me. I was thinking about it but thought maybe it will slow down the process